# Apache Phoenix JDBC connection zookeeper error

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-zookeeper, apache-phoenix

I have Phoenix installed on a 5 node Cloudera cluster with 3 zookeeper nodes.

I’m trying to run a basic SQL command from the JDBC program below but I’m getting zookeeper errors. Could anybody advise?

```
import java.sql.*;

public class PhoenixJDBC {

 public static void main(String args[]) {

 try {
     //Register JDBC Driver
     Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver").newInstance();

     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:54.152.31.122","","");

     //Create a Statement class to execute the SQL statement
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

     //Execute the SQL statement and get the results in a Resultset
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from US_POPULATION");

     // Iterate through the ResultSet, displaying two values
     // for each row using the getString method

     while (rs.next())
         System.out.println("Name= " + rs.getString("host"));
 }
 catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 }
```

Exception:

```
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Can't get connection to ZooKeeper: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
     at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.parseServerException(ServerUtil.java:108)
     at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.ensureTableCreated(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:832)
     at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.createTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1126)
     at org.apache.phoenix.query.DelegateConnectionQueryServices.createTable(DelegateConnectionQueryServices.java:110)
     at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:1590)
     at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:568)
     at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateTableCompiler$2.execute(CreateTableCompiler.java:175)
     at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:271)
     at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:263)
     at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
     at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:261)
     at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeUpdate(PhoenixStatement.java:1043)
     at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$9.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1551)
     at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$9.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1520)
     at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:77)
     at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1520)
     at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:162)
     at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:126)
     at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:133)
     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
     at mysqljbdctest.PhoenixJDBC.main(PhoenixJDBC.java:15)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Can't get connection to ZooKeeper: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(HConnectionManager.java:1651)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(HConnectionManager.java:1677)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(HConnectionManager.java:1884)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHTableDescriptor(HConnectionManager.java:2671)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getTableDescriptor(HBaseAdmin.java:397)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getTableDescriptor(HBaseAdmin.java:402)
     at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.ensureTableCreated(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:764)
     ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 3):

From the stacktrace it looks like HMaster might be down.

Also, Have you tried entering the full zookeeper quorum in your URL? Something like this:

```
jdbc:phoenix:54.152.31.122,54.152.31.123,54.152.31.124
```

I had a problem on Amazon (is that where your cluster is?) where internal and external IPs were getting confused and zookeeper couldn't connect to HBase properly. I solved this (not the most scalable solution but it works!) by creating aliases in /etc/hosts on the machines in the cluster pointing at internal IP addresses, then on my local desktop using the same aliases but pointing to the external IPs. Then, altered my cluster setup to use aliases everywhere instead of IP addresses. Quick way to test if this is your problem - build your app, copy it onto one of the servers in your cluster, and see if it will run ok on there.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

/hbase is default directory in Zookeeper. You have to check in hbase-site.xml what path did hbase be keeped in Zookeeper - May be /hbase-unsecure.

Let's try

```
jdbc:phoenix:zk-host:port:path_on_zookeeper
```